# Which is faster/better: UPDATE WHERE IN or MERGE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table, `TBL1`, with only GUIDs.

I have another table, `TBL2`, in which the primary key is GUID and it also has some other columns. I want to update one of the columns in `TBL2` table based on whether the GUID is in `TBL1`.

Which of the following queries is faster and/or more reliable to use for that?

```
MERGE INTO [db].[dbo].[TBL1] AS target
    USING [db].[dbo].[TBL2] as source
        ON target.GUID = source.GUID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            StatusColumn = 0;
```

or

```
UPDATE [db].[dbo].[TBL1]
    SET StatusColumn=0
    WHERE GUID IN (SELECT GUID FROM [db].[dbo].[TBL2])
```

or maybe something else?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What does the execution plan say for both statements.

Comment: *Generally* `WHERE IN` is not recommended.  `WHERE EXISTS` is more generally accepted.  But the nity gritty aside: `MERGE` is designed to do *more* not *faster*.  But why take someones word, why not test all the options yourself?  *[Also, note that using a GUID as a Primary Key is often not recommended either.  If your PK is your clustered key, you will fragment the table like no-body's business - Because GUID's are not generated in sequence, new entries need inserting at random positions within the table, and not just at the end.]*

Comment: @Dems - good advice.  I would add that if you're using Guids for primary keys, just create them  (or change them) to non-clustered.  We noticed significant performance increases in our environment by making that change.

Comment: @Dems Why isn't `WHERE IN` recommended? Thanks for the tip about clustered GUIDs by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question can only come from the execution plan. From the plan you posted (http://i.imgur.com/6vB2t.png) we can see the following:

- IN is producing a left *semi* join. This is a little more efficient. There is also an optimizer weakness which causes the optimizer not to generate a semi join from an explicit join even if it could.
- Merge is sorting rows. This is because you might get duplicates from your join! If that was impossible merge would be just as fast.
- I guess the explicit join version is exactly as fast as merge.

Diagnosing this without a plan is just guessing. Look at the plan and/or measure. The measuring provides the answer, but the plan provides the **understanding** of the answer.

Comment: Bear in mind that the execution plan changes as statistics change. Fragmentation, concurrency, and a whole host of other real world factors too.  It's not a static answer.

Comment: If the plans are the same and there is no special reason to believe that they might diverge (can't think of any) it _is_ a static answer.

Comment: Here's the execution plan I get. http://i.imgur.com/6vB2t.png Seems like the merge is almost twice as slow...

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest way would probably be a third option using a join:

```
UPDATE t1 SET StatusColumn=0
FROM db.dbo.TBL1 t1
INNER JOIN db.dbo.TBL2 t2 ON t1.guid = t2.guid
```

Comment: +1 : As every record in t1 matches 0 or 1 records in t2, I also think that this would be the fastest option.

Comment: Why would that be faster? The merge is equivalent to your version, as is the update statement. Who knows if the optimizer will be able to generate the same plan? I don't but I *guess* it will.

Comment: @usr - It may generate the same plan for all three, but using a join is the most direct way of telling the optimizer exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Experience tells me that certain patterns are almost always equivalent. Looking at the plan provides this kind of understanding (see my answer).

Comment: Yes, this produced the exact same plan as the `where in` query.